# Eclipse << Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no BioCpp in java.library.path >> HELP!

Tags: java, eclipse, path

Hi guys
I've some problems with my project compilation and run.

My Java project (called BioTesi) tries to load a library called BioCpp.dll, ma it doesn't succeed. I am usin' Eclipse.

What could it be?

Comment: exception message along with code would be useful

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the DLL is not on the PATH if you're using Windows.

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html